# Reloading form does not update in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a form, where when the user clicks on the edit button to edit the text, it works fine. But when user clicks on the update button then reload the page it does not show the updated text after reloading the page.
Here is the plunker, that it worked but the code below does not work when page reloads. (I want to do this only with Front-End)

http://plnkr.co/edit/yyDf2SuEvefLWIK13kS4?p=preview

> Here is my code.

```
    <div class="people-view">
  <h2 class="name">{{people.first}}</h2>
    <h2 class="name">{{people.last}}</h2>

  <span class="title">{{people.title}}</span>

  <span class="date">{{people.date}} </span>

</div> 




<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="list-view">

  <form>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

  <b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.first">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.last">
  <br>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <input type="email" ng-model="people.email">
  <br>
  <b>Phone:</b>
  <input type="num"  ng-model="people.phone">
  <br>
  <b>Website:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.website">
  <br>
  <b>Education:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.education">
  <br>
  <b>Education Year:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.year">

  <br>
  <legend>Address</legend>


<b>Street:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.street">
  <br>
  <b>City:</b>
    <input type="text" ng-model="people.city">
    <br>
    <b>State:</b>
      <input type="text" ng-model="people.state">
      <br>
      <b>Zip:</b>
        <input type="text" ng-model="people.zip">
    <br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
          Edit
        </button>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="save()">Save</button>



</form>

</div>
</div>
```

> App.js

```
    var app = angular.module("Portal", []);



app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inactive = true;
  $scope.save = function() {

   $scope.msg = 'Data sent: '+ JSON.stringify($scope.people);

  };

});
```

> JSON file

```
    [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "img": "//placehold.it/100x100",
    "title": "Family",
    "date": "Joined 4/2/17",
    "email": "jsmith@email.com",
    "phone": "555-555-5555",
    "website": "www.google.com",
    "education": "NYU Law",
    "year": "2008",
    "street": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "1234567"


  },
]
```

> Controller

```
    app.controller('PeopleController',['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
function($scope, people, $routeParams) {
  people.success(function(data) {
    $scope.people = data[$routeParams.id];


  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the prevent default handler:

```
ng-click="save($event)"
```

In your controller, you can put:

```
$scope.save = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $scope.msg = 'Data sent: '+ JSON.stringify($scope.people);
}
```

Comment: I think you cant change JSON file with only angular

Comment: @Jonathan Brizio So, I applied the code and I am not yet seeing any changes when save button is clicked. If you like I can update my plunker or my question above

Comment: @John you cant change JSON file with only angular . But you can change the view by put json file in cookies , showing data in it , and change cookies to change the view . But JSON file not change

Comment: How about can you update the object with the new values so those changes would be reflected in the app?

Answer (score 0):

to make your changes permanent you have to store it to some sort of storage. files is ok but it's not the best choice. So you may consider using local storage. here is good tutorial of how to handle 
[local-storage](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/). so the controller will be like

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.people = {
        "first": "John", 
        "last": "Smith"
    }

    $scope.myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject')) || {
        first : $scope.people.first,
        last : $scope.people.last
    }; 

    $scope.updateThingy = function(){
        $scope.people.first = $scope.myObject.first;
        $scope.people.last = $scope.myObject.last;
        localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify($scope.myObject));
    };
}]);
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/98i64mvwr1oMCmeqiD1y?p=preview). Good luck

Comment: can you show me the local storage prior to my code above?

Comment: If I put the json file as a separate file, will it still work ?

Comment: yes, it will still work and the best way to prove it. Is to code it

Comment: BUT, can you check my update question in the html part: which theres a class "people-view" that part it doesn't update the current name from the form. You know why? Also, can you show me in the plunker update of grabbing it from a separate JSON file

Comment: now the form for other user it only shows John Smith instead of Jane Smith

Comment: Only the form is being updated, but no title as show in my code above.

Comment: hey the form updates but when you go to other users detail page it shows the same user which in this case is "John Smith" in all forms.

Comment: did you update the plunker? Because its not working anymore

Comment: No, I haven't update the plunker and I don't understand the question in the comments

Comment: basically, when I reload the page the form doesn't be saved. for example: When in Jane Doe page the form shows John Smith instead of Jane Doe in the form.

Comment: when using the same way you do it in the plunker,  I get a empty fields in my form.

Comment: sure you missed something. can you illustrate your problem in new plunker and try to explain it in details

Comment: Now, I got it to work. But all I need to do to achieve is when user goes to other user's page for instance "Jane Doe", the form still shows up as "John Smith"

Comment: $scope.myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject')) || {
            first : $scope.people.first,
            last : $scope.people.last
      };
the whole idea is to check if there is a value in the local storage. if there is a value then parse it in the correct format if not then get the default one form the json file. I hope it's clear now. good luck one more time

Comment: Yes, I get that. But, all I want to know, why is duplicating my form to other users. When, updating the form.

Comment: I think you are using the same identifier. localStorage.getItem('myObject') 'myObject' in this example. then my be you are going to add id to every user and use and use it as identifier. I hope that answers your question

Comment: if you want I can post my full code and you can help me?

Comment: probably it's good idea to make it. in a new question and yes add all of your code to it

Comment: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773221/duplicate-form-in-angularjs

Comment: Now, you understand why is doing it like that?